# Navigate to the latest modified path/folder in bash

Tags: bash, unix

I am trying to achieve to do a "cd" command in bash to navigate to the latest folder created. The current approach i have implemented is too long winded. I was wondering if i am able to achieve this with only one line of code.

"4122536" will dynamically change if new folder is created. 
"RLM Reporting File Sample" folder will also be dynamically created.

e.g
Targer Directory Path : /opt/tableau/tableau_rlm/deployment/4122536/ApplicationPackage/RLM Reporting File Sample/

Current approach i implemented to get to the target path in bash

```
RLM_BASE_PATH=/opt/tableau/tableau_rlm/deployment

## Navigate to the latest folder
cd $RLM_BASE_PATH

## This will navigate to 4122536 folder
cd "$(\ls -1dt ./*/ | head -n 1)"

## Navigate to ApplicationPackage
cd  ApplicationPackage

##Navigate to RLM Reporting File Sample Folder
cd  "$(\ls -1dt ./*/ | head -n 1)"


##set pwd variable to rewritable permission 
RLM_REPORTING_PATH="$(pwd)"
echo $RLM_REPORTING_PATH
chmod -R 777 $RLM_REPORTING_PATH/*
```

I have tried implementing below script however

```
## Script 1: Worked only to navigate till the latest folder which is 4122536
cd /home/mm13854/shtest/"$(\ls -1dt ./*/ | head -n 1)"

## As soon i tried adding /application/... , it Will return Error on directory not found
cd /opt/tableau/tableau_rlm/deployment/"$(\ls -1dt ./*/ | head -n 1)/ApplicationPackage/"$(\ls -1dt ./*/ | head -n 1)/
```

Comment: Latest directory **created** or **modified**? It may not be possible to find the creation time because file systems don't usually store it. So try to think of an other criterion, like the only directory that doesn't have `ApplicationPackage` or the like

Comment: Like Fravadona said: At lest not in Unix. Maybe with BSD (macos etc.) or Windows you would have a chance. If you sort it by modification date, like you are doing, not that the modification date is updated if a file in the directory has been added or deleted, or got an inode change.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are asking, I think this would work

```
cd "$(ls -td /opt/tableau/tableau_rlm/deployment/*/ApplicationPackage/*/" | head -1)
```

Comment: This won't work in general. Assuming that the first entry produced is a plain file, you would then cd to a file, which is not possible. Since we have bash, you could end your glob pattern in `*/` instead of `*`. This would limit the filename generation to directories. Also you better wrapp your expression into quotes, in case the directory names contain spaces.

Comment: Thanks, user1934428, I've applied your suggestions.